# Set default image sizes in WordPress to hard crop

Tags: images

How do I set the medium and large images sizes in WP to hard crop?

In my theme I can set the thumbnail size to hard crop using this:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 96, 96, true );
```

But I can see no way to make the medium and large images to hard crop.

Is there possibly a way to remove the medium and large sizes and re-add them using:

```
add_image_size( 'medium', $width, $height, true );
add_image_size( 'large', $width, $height, true );
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can over write the default like this:

```
add_image_size( 'medium', 200, 200, true );
```

Comment: Yes it was this simple! I was so convinced it couldn't be that...

Answer (score 33):

Here's an improvement that uses the settings as you tried to do:

`add_image_size('medium', get_option( 'medium_size_w' ), get_option( 'medium_size_h' ), true );`

Comment: the benefit from this solution is, that you still can set the measurements in the wp setting. sweet.

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

To enable cropping for the `medium` images, it is enough to use this code:

```
update_option( 'medium_crop', 1 );
```

The [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/#description) function  itself checks whether such an option exists, and adds it if necessary:

> If the option does not exist, then the option will be added with the option value, with an `$autoload` value of `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

The Gleb's answer worked nicely for me.

```
// Medium Size Thumbnail
if(false === get_option('medium_crop')) {
    add_option('medium_crop', '1'); 
} else {
    update_option('medium_crop', '1');
}
```

Found the full code [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-turn-on-cropping-for-thumbnails-in-wordpress/)